# Passing Elements from Array into Database by specific key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I am trying to pass elements from the array into my database by using a specific key. First, my elements were in a multi-dimensional area and I transfer them into a simple array. I want to pass those elements into my database using a specific key.

For example, if the key from the array is equal to 0, then while I fill my array I would like to put the value of the element in the first column of the table in the database. My code looks like this

```
foreach ($aDataTableDetailHTML as $array) {

   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

      $newArray[$key] = $value;

      if ($key == "1") {

          $sql = "INSERT INTO Earthquake(DateOf) VALUES ('$value')";

      } else {

          $sql = "INSERT INTO Earthquake(Comments) VALUES ('$value')";
   }

mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

}
```

Comment: can you show your $aDataTableDetailHTML as json format?

Comment: I am only keen with php I haven't used json before

Comment: just paste this code before the main foreach echo json_encode($aDataTableDetailHTML);die; copy output and show us here

Comment: Some of the output is:[["2019\/03\/16","10:11:31.9","55.794","-6.353","7","1.8","","ISLAY,ARGYLL & BUTE",""],["2019\/03\/14","14:30:59.7","52.085","-2.898","23","2.4","","BYFORD,HEREFORD",""],["2019\/03\/14","01:00:57.8","51.163","-0.250","2","0.0","","NEWDIGATE,SURREY",""],["2019\/03\/10","06:51:21.2","51.163","-0.251","1","-0.3","","NEWDIGATE,SURREY",""],["2019\/03\/08","02:39:41.2","51.163","-0.241","2","0.3","","NEWDIGATE,SURREY",""],["2019\/03\/08","02:40:30.4","51.163","-0.239","2","-0.1","","NEWDIGATE,SURREY",""],

Comment: ok now tell me what error are you facing during this process? Or your code is inserting your data in the database? According to Your JSON data your foreach is correct just need to replace $key == '1' to $key == '0' to insert DateOf column

Comment: I did that but still not included in the database.

Comment: Do you have only one column in both Tables?

Comment: No I have 9 columns in Earthquake table and 9 places in the array

Comment: I found the problem! The problem was that I have to put the variables as null in the database

Answer (score 0):

Try This, Hope this helps in your second loop

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i');
echo'<pre>';print_r($array);
$sizeOfArray = (sizeof($array) - 1);
$values = "INSERT INTO Earthquake(Your Columns) VALUES (";
$i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
       $values .="'" . $value . "'";
       if ($i < $sizeOfArray) {
           $values .= ",";
       }
       $i++;
    }
 $values .= ");";
 echo $values;die;
```

**My Output is:**
INSERT INTO Earthquake(Your Columns) VALUES ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i');

Comment: I found the problem! I had to put the elements as NULL in the database! Thanks a lot!